# How to let 3 divs displayed in line, won't wrap if I resize the browser?

Tags: css, html

Please see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Freewind/Vkp4U/

The html:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="x">x</div>
    <div class="y">y</div>
    <div class="z">z</div>
</div>​
```

The css:

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll-x;
}

.x {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float:left;
}

.y {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    float:left;
}

.z {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float:left;
}​
```

How to let the 3 inner divs displayed in line, won't wrap if I resize the browser to smaller?

Limitations:

1. the width of outer div should not be specified
2. the width of inner divs are fixed

Comment: Please rephrase/ask your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can define display table and table-cell in you css properties as like this

**Css**

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll-x;

    display:table;
}

.x {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display:table-cell;
}

.y {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display:table-cell;
}

.z {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="x">x</div>
<div class="y">y</div>
<div class="z">z</div>
</div>​
​
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/Vkp4U/5/

Comment: When I resize the browser to small size, that inner divs are all resized, but I want them have fixed widths

Answer (score 1):

this may work:
The idea here is to set the outer as relative postion. now all the absolute sub div will refer to their parent relative div. (demo here:http://jsfiddle.net/Vkp4U/7/)

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll-x;
    position:relative;
}

.x {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
}

.y {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:400px;
}

.z {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:800px;
}​
```

Comment: This works as I expected, but not convenient that we have to hardcode the `left`

Comment: i agree, but without width constraint on parent div, i think there is no other way to force box model to keep inner div positions. floating is an indication, not an order. left forces box model layout.

Answer (score 1):

Use % in css width...

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll-x;
}

.x {
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float:left;
}

.y {
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    float:left;
}

.z {
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float:left;
}​
```

Comment: I updated the question that the inner divs should have fixed widths.